# Candlestck and OHLC chart in Annotated Timeline, Google Visualization

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to draw candlestick and OHLC charts on Annotated time line now? Or any announcement about this. Since Google finance already has all the features.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api/msg/8187f49dee43d311

no, but it will be there soon(tm) :)

Comment: Please don't just post links to answers.